# Why is call to super failing here

Tags: ruby

```
 module A
   def foo
     if super.respond_to? :foo
        puts 'super responded to :foo'
     end
   end
 end

 class Lab
   include A
 end

 puts Lab.ancestors.inspect #=> Lab, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
 Lab.new.foo
```

`foo': super: no superclass method`foo' for # (NoMethodError)

I was assuming that in this case the call to super would go to `Object` and then to `BasicObject` and finally false would be returned.

Why I'm getting `no superclass method foo` ?

I'm using ruby 1.9.3 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Super calls the method of the same name on a parent class.

```
if super.respond_to? foo
```

That line will be calling foo on any parent class in the hierachy.

EDIT:

You probably want to do something like

```
self.ancestors.select{|a| a.respond_to? :foo}.size > 0
```

as the check.

Comment: +1 for looking beyond the erroneous call to `super.respond_to?` and imagining a solution (`self.ancestors.select`)

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't really make sense: you guard the call to `super` with a condition, but you are calling `super` in that condition anyway. In other words: you are calling `super` in order to determine whether it is safe to call `super`. Therefore, you will get an error if there is no method called `foo` in the ancestry chain.

Comment: Yes bad example. Fixed it.

Comment: You are *still* calling `super` in the condition. You just removed the call to `super` that was guarded by that condition. I repeat: calling `super` in order to check whether you can call `super` simply *doesn't work*. It makes no sense. You want to prevent calling `super` if it is not defined but you call `super` in order to figure out whether it is defined.